# Shell script to run HiveQL queries

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix, hive

I am new to Unix Shell Scripting world. I wanted to run a simple sql query from the unix shell script and output the result in a .txt file and then send that .txt file as an attachment in an email.

SQL Query and piping the output to a txt file:

```
SELECT count(*) from pds_table > a.txt;
```

How can I do this from a shell script and send the output to a txt file and then send that txt file as an attachment in an email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
hive -e 'SELECT count(*) from pds_table' > a.txt
```

You can find more information here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli

After that you should be able to send an email with your attachment wherever you like using mutt. Note that you need to create some nice preformatted_mail.txt file which looks like the way you want it.

```
#!/bin/bash
hive -e 'SELECT count(*) from pds_table' > attachment.tmp
mutt -s "Daily logs" -a attachment.tmp some@email.you.like < preformatted_mail.txt
```

Comment: I know I can do by this way. But suppose If I need to run the same query to run on a daily basis and send the a.txt file as an attachment in an email? Then how I can do that, that's what I wanted to do..

Comment: Sorry, didn't fully read your question. ;) Updated with a suggestion using mutt.

Comment: Thanks Amestig for the suggestion, but when I tried doing that, I get ` mutt: not found`. Any other way of sendin email apart from mutt? or some other approach you want me to suggest?

Comment: It should be pretty straigh forward in building or downloading a pre-built package from [mutt website](http://www.mutt.org/download.html). If you're running debian/ubuntu you should be fine with just doing **apt-get install mutt**